# How to design a system backend which user can customize some configuration

Tags: database, model, architecture, backend, system-design

I should model a system that clients can apply some configuration on separated entities.

Let me explain with an example:
We have users that have a config tab in their dashboards.

We have a feature to send notifications on their browsers and we have a feature which we can send an email to them.

We also have a feature as a pop-up.

The user should be able to modify our default notification message, modify our default email template, modify our default text on email or elements.

For the pop-up, The user should be able to modify the width and height of the pop-up, change the default texts, modify background color, change the button location on the pop-up.

And when I want to send an email to the user I should apply these settings on the template then send the email. Also when the front-end wants to show those pop-ups, wants to get these configs from my API and apply them.

These settings will be more and more in the future. So I can not specify a settings table with some fields. I think it is not a good idea.

What can I do? How to design and model this scenario? What are the best practices?
Can I use a NoSQL like MongoDB instead of a relational database?
Thanks a lot.

PS:

- I am using Django to develop this system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have built similar sub-systems before, by hand.

I don't know much about Django, but do some research to see if it has any "out of the box" or community developed / open source add-ons that do what you want.

If you have to do it yourself...

A key-value pair is not going to be enough, but it's close.  You only need a simple data structure:

- **ID** (how your code recognizes this property), e.g. `UserPopupBackgroundColor`.
- **Property name** (what the user see's / how they recognize this property in the UI), e.g. "*Popup Background Color*".
- Optional - **Data type**.  This is essential if you want to do any sensible input validation.  E.g. pop up height should probably expect an integer, and have a sensible min/max value on it, where as an email address is totally different.
- Optional, some kind of flag to identify valid properties.

That last flag is bit of an edge case, but it's useful if you use the subsystem to hold more properties than you want users to have access to.  E.g. imagine you want to get a list of all properties and display the list to the user - are there any 'special' ones you need to filter out that they should not see?

You then need somewhere to put the values, and link them to the user:

- Row **ID** / GUID.  You can use a unique constraint across the **User** and **PropertyID** if you wanted to instead, but personally I find a unique row ID is a reliable and flexible approach for most scenarios.
- **UserID**.
- **PropertyID** - refers to ID mentioned above.
- **PropertyValue**

Depending on how serious you need to get, you can dump all the values into the one `PropertyValue` column (assuming you're persisting this in a database) - which means that column needs to be a string, or, you can add a column per data type.

If you want to add a column per data type, don't kill yourself.  The most I have ever done is:

- `PropertyValue_text` (text/varchar)
- `PropertyValue_int` (or double)
- `PropertyValue_DateTime` (date/time - surprise!!)

So when I say 'column per data type' I mean per data type your stack needs/wants to handle - not the 'optional' data types you define in the logic - since that data type is partially just about input validation.

Obviously if you use different logical data types, you can map those to data type columns in the database.  The reasons for doing this (using the different data types in the database are:

1. To reduce the amount of casting you need to do (code to database, and vis-a-versa).
2. To leverage database level query features, which can be useful.  E.g. find emails values and verify them; find expired date values; etc.

It takes a bit of work to build all this, but it's powerful once you get set-up because you can add any number of properties.  If you are using the 'full' solution with explicit data types then adding new logical data types isn't too painful if you already have a few set-up.

Before you design and build this, think about future reuse, and anyway you can package it up for later - or community use.  Remember it impact all layers (UI, logic and data).

**Final tip** - when coming up with the property ID's (that the code uses) make them human readable, and use some sort of naming convention so that adding new ones later is easy and follows a predictable path.

**Update** - Defining **Property** and **PropertyValue** in database tables is an obvious way to go.  Depending on the situation you can also define **Property** in code - especially if you don't add new ones or change existing ones very frequently.  Another bonus is that if you're in an MVP situation you can use the code effectively as a stub, and build out the database/persistence part for that later.

Comment: Thank You, This was very useful. But I have a question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If we want to have default config of these properties we created. To use for our tasks until the user want to customize them, what is the good way for handle this?
Can we add default value field on the property table(The first one you say)? @adrian-k

Comment: Yes that would be a good approach - DefaultValue (optional) on the Property.